# MPAndroidChart how to adjust x-axis range

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

On my Horizontal Bar Chart I have a button that adds a new entry to the chart as a new bar. However, this bar which is 26.0, is too large for my x-axis range from 1-10. How can I increase the x-axis range when the button is pressed.

Comment: post your code too...

Answer (score 0):

Add from following lines to your code for your respective axis on button press and give the largest value in following code:

```
lineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(your_value);
lineChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMaxValue(your_value);
```